# Custom line in barplot (multiple barplots)

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

My data frame:

```
    N   P   E   S
W1 3.5 3.5 3.4 3.5
w2 3.4 3.7 3.6 3.5
w3 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
w4 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
w5 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
w6 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
w7 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
w8 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
```

and code for barplot

```
mat <- as.matrix(t(tabela.matrix))

qw <- barplot(mat, beside = TRUE, axisnames = FALSE, ylim = c(0, 6),
              col = c("yellow", "deepskyblue1", "yellowgreen", "orchid4"))

text(colMeans(qw[2:3, ]), -0.25, labels = colnames(mat), xpd = TRUE, srt = 15)
text(qw, 0, round(as.matrix(t(tabela.matrix)), 1), cex = 1, pos = 3, srt = 90)

legend(3.2, -0.6, c("N","P","E", "S"),
       fill = c("yellow", "deepskyblue1", "yellowgreen", "orchid4"),
       horiz = TRUE, xpd = TRUE)
```

produces this barplot
[image]

So on my barplot I need to add `line` that indicates subtraction: max-min values per row. So am using below code to get the subtraction.

```
max.tmp <- apply(df, 1, max)
min.tmp <- apply(df, 1, min)
substr.tmp <- max.tmp - min.tmp
```

Now I would like to add red line indicating values in `substr.tmp`. The code `lines()` doesn't work.

My output (red line) should "look" like this (it is picture form excel and i am interested in adding line, not the data in the picture itself)

[image]

---

A `dput` of the data:

```
structure(c(3.46666666666667, 3.35, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.45555555555556, 3.7, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.40769230769231, 3.57692307692308, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.51122994652406, 3.5156862745098, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909 ), .Dim = c(8L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), NULL))
```

Comment: can you add `dput` of the data frame

Comment: @rbm, here it is **structure(c(3.46666666666667, 3.35, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 
3.5, 3.45555555555556, 3.7, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 
3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 
3.40769230769231, 3.57692307692308, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 
3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 
3.51122994652406, 3.5156862745098, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909, 
3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909
), .Dim = c(8L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
"f", "g", "h"), NULL))'**

Comment: your graphs are different - first goes 0 to 3.5 on y axis, the second goes to almost 6. Also in the `max.tmp <- apply(df, 1, max)` it's not clear what the `df` is.. Can you post the entire runable example with `dput` init.

Comment: The second picture is from excel, that someone else generated. I generated the first picture and I need just plot **line** like it is in second picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `data.table` and `ggplot2` packages you could do it as follows:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- melt(setDT(df), id="name")
df2[, difference := max(value) - min(value), by = name]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x=name, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_line(aes(x=name, y=difference, group=1), size=1.5, color="red") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,4)) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"),
                    values = c("yellow", "deepskyblue1", "yellowgreen", "orchid4")) +
  theme_bw()
```

this gives:

[image]

Used data:

```
m <- structure(c(3.46666666666667, 3.35, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.45555555555556, 3.7, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.36666666666667, 3.40769230769231, 3.57692307692308, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.53846153846154, 3.51122994652406, 3.5156862745098, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909, 3.49090909090909 ), .Dim = c(8L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), NULL))
df <- as.data.frame(m)
df$name <- rownames(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

This could work for you, but the differences in your example dataset (along with the one in your comments) will yield a funny looking plot:

```
#original code
mat <- as.matrix(t(tabela.matrix)) ;qw <- barplot(mat, beside=TRUE, axisnames = FALSE,ylim = c(0, 6), col=c("yellow", "deepskyblue1", "yellowgreen","orchid4")) ; text(colMeans(qw[2:3,]), -0.25, labels = colnames(mat), xpd=TRUE, srt=15); legend(3.2,-0.6, c("Nadrejeni","Podrejeni","Enak nivo", "Samoocenjevalec"), fill=c("yellow", "deepskyblue1", "yellowgreen","orchid4"), horiz=TRUE, xpd=TRUE)
text(qw, 0, round(as.matrix(t(tabela.matrix)), 1),cex=1,pos=3,srt=90)
legend(3.2, -0.6, c("N","P","E", "S"),
   fill = c("yellow", "deepskyblue1", "yellowgreen", "orchid4"),
   horiz = TRUE, xpd = TRUE)
#new code
par(new=TRUE)
plot(substr.tmp, lwd=2, col="red", type="l", axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0,6))
axis(4, ylim=c(0,6), col="red",col.axis="red",las=1)
```

Note that this plot has two axes, one black, one red. The red one is for the second plot. If you'd like to remove that, comment the last line. And, according to your expected output, this was kept in the original scale (hence `ylim=c(0,6)`)